# Parler de vs Parler de + article défini?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, articles

Hier, j'ai vu une phrase: **parler d'amour**. Cependant, je pensais qu'utilisation d'un article défini dans la construction **parler de** est indispensable et on dois toujours dire parler de l'amour. Alors, peut on utiliser parler de, sans dire le/la/les?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L'emploi de l'article défini implique en général qu'on parle d'une chose en particulier. Dans ce cas, d'un amour en particulier (parler de l'amour d'un couple par exemple) alors que parler d'amour signifie parler d'amour en général.

Dans le cas d'amour, la distinction n'est pas évidente car il est plus rare que l'on parle d'amour au sens particulier qu'au sens général. Dans le langage courant, "parler d'amour" et "parler de l'amour" sont assez proches selon moi.

C'est plus flagrant avec un autre terme utilisé à la fois au sens particulier et général. "Parler de la guerre" signifie parler d'une guerre en particulier, "Parler de guerre" des guerres en général.

Le verbe parler étant à la fois transitif direct ("parler français"), transitif indirect ("parler de la pluie et du beau temps", "parler à haute voix") et intransitif ("nous avons beaucoup parlé ce soir"), on peut l'utiliser sans dire le/la/les.

Comment: L"absence de préposition va plus loin que le langage parlé ; on trouve dans les livres, par exemple, « [parler cinéma](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22parler%20cin%C3%A9ma%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) » et « [parler mathématiques](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22parler%20math%C3%A9matiques%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) » et il doit y en avoir d'autres. Il n'est pas clair que l'on puisse généraliser, bien que ne vois pas ce qui empêcherait cela : parler grammaire, parler équitation, parler histoire, …

Comment: _Moy j'irois me charger d'une Spirituelle / Qui ne parleroit rien que Cercle et que Ruelle ?_ (Molière) Le tour sans la préposition n'est pas employé uniquement en language parlé ou de manière familière... mais c'est un détail ici.

Comment: OK, réponse mise à jour